# ScaleTo Error in a KINECT Project using Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, kinect

I am still looking for a solution for my problem ...

I need to solve my project problem in ScaleTo() Method Code:

Dim scaledJoint = joint.ScaleTo(ScreenMaxX, ScreenMaxY, 0.5F, 0.2F)

The error says " 'ScaleTo' is not a member of 'Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui.Joint' "

please I need a solution for this... 
Thx

Answer (score 0):

`ScaleTo` is part of the [Coding4Fun Kinect Toolkit](http://c4fkinect.codeplex.com/).  It is not part of the standard Kinect SDK.

Also, the `Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui` namespace represents a very old version of the SDK.  Several major changes have accrued since the release of SDK 1.5, and now SDK 1.7.  You should not be learning on such an obsolete version of the SDK.